# Resource time not allocating correctly in Project 2013

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, software

I'm planning a project where I want my resources to dedicate one day week each to project work.  I've created a calendar for each resource which blocks out their day, so there are Tuesday only, Thursday only, and Friday only calendars.  There's one resource assigned to each calendar at 100%; resource Rob is also assigned to the Friday only calendar, but at only 50%.  The project is set to auto-schedule new tasks and to treat tasks as Fixed Work.

What I want to see is that the first available resource uses all his available hours, so if a task were set to 12 hours of work, the first resource (say the Tuesday one) would do 7 hours of work on it, then the Thursday resource would pick up the remaining 5, and the Friday resources would never actually be utilized.

There are two problems I'm having, illustrated by this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

1. Referring to task BRV, why are Bill and Marty never assigned during the second week?  Ideally, they'd work on the task on Monday and Tuesday, leaving only a few hours on left to be done on March 13.  Why is Project skipping over Bill and Marty's available days on the 2nd Tuesday and Thursday?  Also, for the few hours that should be left on March 13, is there a way to tell Project "always assign Dylan to 100% of  his available time before assigning anything to Rob"?
2. Referring to the CDR task, why are Bill and Marty not assigned a full 7 hours each, but Dylan is assigned to work a full 8 after them?

Comment: It is really difficult to read the detail in that image. Can you construct a textual idealised version of the problem that can be reproduced in my own copy of MS-P?

Comment: A couple of questions:  when you say you've assigned a resource to a calendar - precisely how did you do that?  Usually we assign a resource a base calendar.  Look at the Resource Sheet and what do you see for each resources' base calendar?

As to why resources are assigned work or not - I'll look at Bill and Marty's calendar for the week of March 8 - do they have working time that week?

Comment: Marv: Sorry, thought you'd be able to click the screenshot and zoom in on it.  Here it is larger:  http://s12.postimg.org/ndjf7bt71/Allocation_problem_4.jpg

Comment: Julie: I created calendars called Tuesday only, Thursday only, and Friday only, setting the working days appropriately. I then edited my resources to set one of these as each resource's base calendar. I also set Rob to only 50% availability. Bill and Marty should be available the week of 3/8; their base calendars are set for Thursdays only and Tuesdays only respectively, and there are no unavailable dates set for either of them.  If I add only them to the task, they each get 8 hours for the weeks of 3/11 and 3/8, and then each get 1.5 the week of 3/15. Still not perfect, but close.

Comment: Bill and Marty only have 7 hours of work assigned to them and Dylan has 14.  So, there is no need to Bill and Marty to work the week of 3/11. Did you mean the 35 hours of work to be divided evenly among the resources - or roughly 12 hours of work each?  I recommend splitting your screen to show the Task Form in the lower pane.  Regarding your question about "always assign Dylan" before assigning Rob.  No, sorry.  Assignment of resources is always up to the user.  If the task is effort driven, Project will simply divide the work among the people assigned.